Oracle syntax to Postgres SQL
I'm doing migration from Oracle to Postgres SQL. I have a complex query from Oracle that need to convert.
SELECT a.menu_cd,a.child_menu_cd,a.pos, a.mod_cd,a.func_cd,
a.menu_name, a.BNK_CONCEPT, (select c.cuba_func_id from sy98sec_func_mod c where c.func_cd = a.func_cd and c.mod_cd = a.mod_cd) cuba_func_id,
(SELECT d.func_name FROM sy98sec_func_mod d WHERE d.func_cd = a.func_cd and d.mod_cd = a.mod_cd) func_name, b.counter FROM 
(SELECT o.menu_cd, o.child_menu_cd, o.pos, o.mod_cd, o.func_cd, p.menu_name, o.BNK_CONCEPT FROM sy98menu_det o LEFT OUTER JOIN sy98menu p
ON p.menu_cd = o.child_menu_cd where o.applicable in ('Y', 'B')) a LEFT JOIN (select distinct(FUNC_CD),mod_cd,
COUNT (*) AS counter from sy98sec_perms where  perms_lvl = '99' AND perms_grp = 'ADMIN' GROUP BY func_cd, mod_cd) 
b ON b.func_cd = a.func_cd AND b.mod_cd = a.mod_cd WHERE b.counter IS NOT NULL OR a.func_cd IS NULL
START WITH a.menu_cd = 'MAIN' CONNECT BY a.menu_cd = PRIOR a.child_menu_cd ORDER SIBLINGS BY a.pos

Since Postgres cannot use START WITH, i trying to do an adjustment on this query so that it will compatible and my application can run.
WITH RECURSIVE menu_hierarchy AS (
  -- Base case: Start with the root menu item
  SELECT 
    a.menu_cd,
    a.child_menu_cd,
    a.pos, 
    a.mod_cd,
    a.func_cd,
    a.menu_name, 
    a.BNK_CONCEPT, 
    (SELECT c.cuba_func_id FROM sy98sec_func_mod c WHERE c.func_cd = a.func_cd AND c.mod_cd = a.mod_cd) AS cuba_func_id,
    (SELECT d.func_name FROM sy98sec_func_mod d WHERE d.func_cd = a.func_cd AND d.mod_cd = a.mod_cd) AS func_name,
    b.counter,
    a.menu_cd AS root_menu_cd,
    1 AS level
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
      o.menu_cd, 
      o.child_menu_cd, 
      o.pos, 
      o.mod_cd, 
      o.func_cd, 
      p.menu_name, 
      o.BNK_CONCEPT 
    FROM 
      sy98menu_det o 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sy98menu p ON p.menu_cd = o.child_menu_cd 
    WHERE 
      o.applicable IN ('Y', 'N')) a 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
      DISTINCT(FUNC_CD), 
      mod_cd, 
      COUNT(*) AS counter 
    FROM 
      sy98sec_perms 
    WHERE  
      perms_lvl = 99 
      AND perms_grp = 'ADMIN'
    GROUP BY 
      func_cd, 
      mod_cd) b 
    ON b.func_cd = a.func_cd 
    AND b.mod_cd = a.mod_cd 
  WHERE a.menu_cd = 'MAIN'
  
  UNION ALL
  
  -- Recursive case: Join with child items
  SELECT 
    a.menu_cd,
    a.child_menu_cd,
    a.pos, 
    a.mod_cd,
    a.func_cd,
    a.menu_name, 
    a.BNK_CONCEPT, 
    (SELECT c.cuba_func_id FROM sy98sec_func_mod c WHERE c.func_cd = a.func_cd AND c.mod_cd = a.mod_cd) AS cuba_func_id,
    (SELECT d.func_name FROM sy98sec_func_mod d WHERE d.func_cd = a.func_cd AND d.mod_cd = a.mod_cd) AS func_name,
    b.counter,
    h.root_menu_cd,
    h.level + 1 AS level
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
      o.menu_cd, 
      o.child_menu_cd, 
      o.pos, 
      o.mod_cd, 
      o.func_cd, 
      p.menu_name, 
      o.BNK_CONCEPT 
    FROM 
      sy98menu_det o 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sy98menu p ON p.menu_cd = o.child_menu_cd 
    WHERE 
      o.applicable IN ('Y', 'N')) a 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
      DISTINCT(FUNC_CD), 
      mod_cd, 
      COUNT(*) AS counter 
    FROM 
      sy98sec_perms 
    WHERE  
      perms_lvl = 99 
      AND perms_grp = 'ADMIN'
    GROUP BY 
      func_cd, 
      mod_cd) b 
    ON b.func_cd = a.func_cd 
    AND b.mod_cd = a.mod_cd 
  JOIN menu_hierarchy h ON h.child_menu_cd = a.menu_cd
)

-- Final select from the recursive CTE without root_menu_cd and level
SELECT 
  menu_cd,
  child_menu_cd,
  pos, 
  mod_cd,
  func_cd,
  menu_name, 
  BNK_CONCEPT, 
  cuba_func_id,
  func_name,
  counter
FROM menu_hierarchy
ORDER BY root_menu_cd, level, pos;

I'm using this query but my data not sorting as what it supposed to.
Oracle Result
Postgres Result
As you can see the result is there but not sorting properly

you "ORDER BY root_menu_cd" but you don't show the column in your result...
anyway without test data difficult to help.

Offtopic: Why do you use DISTINCT (as a function?) when the GROUP BY makes distinct groups? Without data (in plain text) it's not even clear if there is a problem at all.
